# Python BeautifulSoup get field of div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a value from here:

```
<div class="rvm-price mr-15">
   <input type="hidden" id="product_price_int" value="230000">
   <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="IDR">Rp </span>
   <span itemprop="price">230.000</span>
</div>
```

And this is how I'm trying to get a value:

```
price = soup.find_all(id = 'product_price_int')
```

The output:

```
[<input id="product_price_int" type="hidden" value="230000"/>]
```

How can I get just 230000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is a list, you can do `price[0]` to get the first element of that list. If you want to access the value of the value property from it, you can do so using `price[0]['value']`.

Comment: price[0].value gives None, however, price[0]['value'] gives the right output.
Thank you.

Comment: Embarrassing! Fixed now, thank you for the heads up.